# Jenkins pipelines exception java.io.NotSerializableException : hudson.model.User

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, hudson

I am creating a Jenkins Pipeline project using declarative Grovvy pipeline. In that there is a ask where I have to set a timeout for certain operation and if the task is not completed in the defined time duration, then I have to run some cleanup commands in shell. Setup goes something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
import com.vmware.jenkins.utils.JenkinsGroovyCommon
.
.
def user
wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) { user = env.BUILD_USER_ID }
print "DEBUG: parameter USERNAME = ${user}"   // Output : DEBUG: parameter USERNAME = xyz   
stage ('Verify') {
  try {
        timeout(time: 2, unit: 'MINUTES') { 
          print "${env.BUILD_USER_ID}" // Output : xyz
          print "Do some verification"
          .
          .
          .
         }
       } 
  catch(err) {
       def inputuser = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
       if('SYSTEM' == inputuser.toString()) {
         print "${env.BUILD_USER_ID}" // Output : null
         print " ${BUILD_URL} has reached an input timeout, failing build."
         message = "${BUILD_URL} has reached an input timeout, failing build."
       }
       try {
             sh '''
                 echo "Do cleanup!"
             '''
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 print "Failed to exeucute cleanup : " + e
            }
     }
```

(I have provided outputs inline for each of print statements)
When I execute above pipeline, the control never comes to following shell script

```
  sh '''
      echo "Do cleanup!"
  '''
```

Rather it throws the exception

```
Failed to exeucute cleanup : java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.User
```

As from the output we can see that **env.BUILD_USER_ID** is getting set to **null** looks like **hudson.model.User** is also **null**.

Looks like after timeout, these variables are resetting. How do I avoid these null values and make **hudson.model.User** carry the same value as it had before? Or any other approach you guys would suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter such problem when I use the multibranch pipeline, it happens because jenkins needs to serialize the procedures such as step or stage at some point in case that jenkins restart, so it can reprocess those procedures.

The exception "Failed to exeucute cleanup : java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.User" indicate that jenkins try to serialize the Object user, but it can not be serialized. The line of code :
`def inputuser = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()`
 
cause the exception. Usually, we can try to use variable of Type belong to String or Number, these types are easy to be serialized. So, to solve the exception, you can change the code like this: 

`def inputuser = err.getCauses()[0].getUser().toString()`